# How can I schedule a script to copy a file from a remote server to my local machine every hour with a time stamp using CRON & SCP?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

I'm a programming apprentice and have recently been given a job to complete on the terminal and I need some help or just some pointers in the right direction as to what I need to do.

I need to copy a certain file from a remote server and back it up every hour with a time stamp included. I know how to connect to servers using SSH and I also know how to transfer files using SCP - it's just writing the script I need some help with. I know that I will need to use CRON to schedule it I just don't know how I can put everything together. I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a shell script thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp username@host:file.log file.log.`date +%H%M%S`
```

(error checking elided - don't forget to make it executable via `chmod u+x`)

The date invocation takes the current date/time, creates a timestamp and appends it to the destination log file name. So you'll get something like:

```
file.log.131504
```

That's time-based, but you'll likely want a date instead. For more info see [here](http://nixshell.wordpress.com/2007/03/11/timestamps-for-log-files/) and the [date man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) for formatting options.

Note that jobs under cron run with a cut down environment (reduced PATH etc.). So be sure to set all appropriate environment variables in your script, cd to the correct directory etc., and log the results via something like:

```
* * * * * /home/user/mycronscript.sh 2>&1 >/tmp/test.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brian. So you know where you have put: scp username etc.. is that the script I need to create but obviously change the username and host etc.. to my details and the file I want to trasnfer?

Comment: That's exactly it. Get the script running standalone and then add it to cron once you're happy with it

Comment: Thanks for your help. Thought that was it. Just one more question I have changed the permissions on the file to all but it keeps asking for the password every time I run the script so surely I cant be typing in the password every hour? is there any way I can bypass the password being asked?